# tensorflow 1.x reshape placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

From TF v1.x as shown below, `x` is an entry with dim [None, 784] to train my example model.

It looks similar to [?, 784] from tensorboard.

For some reason, I have to reshape `x` to `[1, 784]` to predict, that is `x` needs to look like `[1, 784]` instead of `[?, 784]` to predict after training the model.

Any suggestions?

```
with tf.name_scope('Input_Layer'):
    x = tf.placeholder("float",shape=[None, 784]
                       ,name="x")
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The "?" in tensorflow indicates that this dimension is not fixed. So it can vary from call to call. The function predict expects a shaped tensor `[n_examples,784]` where `n_examples` is the number of examples.

In your case, since you only need to predict one example, you need to reshape it to `[1,784]` , i.e., `n_examples=1`

Comment: Thanks your comment. As your description, I know I could input `[1, 784]`, But actually, My job is  convert the model to hardware DSP. it only accept fixed dim as input.